# What is the number when you multiply all its digits and you get the number itself? And how to implemen in python?

Tags: python

The task: Using a "for" loop, write a program that only displays a number if the result of multiplying all the numbers in a two-digit number (from 10 to 99) is the same as the number itself.

I'm making a program that only displays numbers if the result of multiplying all the digits in a two-digit number (from 10 to 99) is the same as the number itself. I've try this code, but it's not true:

```py
for num in range(10, 100):
    first_digits = num // 10
    second_digits = num % 10

    if first_digits == second_digits:
        print(num)
```

Comment: You're not multiplying anything. How is this an honest attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: There aren't any such numbers so how us this useful?

Comment: As @user19077881 wrote, there is something wrong with this task. Multiplying two digits a×b is never going to be equal to a×10+b. So either you misunderstood your task, or the solution is a program which does nothing.

Comment: @user19077881 et al: The correct answer may *well* be that "there are none". The idea behind these sort of teaching tasks is *not* to get an answer, it's to teach someone how to code (and think, design, debug, etc).

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? What ***precisely*** are you having difficulty with? [ask]

Comment: i've task like this and i confused that question : Using a "for" loop, write a program that only displays a number if the result of multiplying all the numbers in a two-digit number (from 10 to 99) is the same as the number itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code checks if the tens digit is equal to the units digit, which is not the condition you described.

You can modify your code as follows:

```
for num in range(10, 100):
    tens_digit = num // 10
    units_digit = num % 10

    product_of_digits = tens_digit * units_digit

    if product_of_digits == num:
        print(num)
```

Comment: What is  the difference between this solution and the one previously provided?

Comment: @Onyambu: for a start, it details what was *wrong* with OP's original solution. The other one appears to be a code dump. Those sort of answers *are* valuable, since they provide a solution, but I prefer those that educate rather than just solve. Even if they're similar and posted later (since I vote for the best answer rather than the fastest answer - see https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/10/06/solving-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/).

Comment: An answer with just one code line `pass` produces the same (correct) result ie. no output.

Comment: @user19077881: yes, but so is not doing anything at all, as is using mathematical proofs to avoid writing the code. Yet, despite the same answer, those are both incorrect as they don't achieve the goal in setting this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
for num in range(10, 100):
    first_digits = num // 10
    second_digits = num % 10
    if first_digits * second_digits == num:
        print(num)
```